# does $f^{-1}(y)=\bar f^{-1}(y-f(x_0))$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Define a function $\bar f(x)=f(x)-f(x_0), f:R\to R$ i want to ask does $f^{-1}(y)=\bar f^{-1}(y-f(x_0))$? I ask this question as i am not sure if there is a typo in the notes as $f^{-1}(y)=\bar f^{-1}(y+f(x_0))$ but i dont quite see why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x = f^{-1}(y)$ means $f(x) = y$ (where $f$ is assumed to be one-to-one).
$x = {\overline{f}}^{-1}(y - f(x_0))$ means $\overline{f}(x) = y - f(x_0)$, i.e.
$f(x) = y$.  So yes, they are the same.

Comment: I guess there are some typo in the note. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why "in advance"?  You can only thank me in advance before I do something for you, not after.